# Why does my keras model return more metrics than I specified?

Tags: keras, model, metrics, loss-function, sequential

I defined a simple generative adversarial network that consists of a generator and a discriminator. The generator is compiled two times: The first time for non-adversarial training (without the discriminator extension), and the second one for adversarial training.

After I have built and compiled everything, I can ask my compiled models for their losses and metrics. This is what I get:

- **net.generator.loss** -> 'mean_absolute_error'
- **net.generator.metrics** -> []
- **net.combined.loss** -> ['mean_absolute_error', 'binary_crossentropy']
- **net.combined.metrics** -> []

So far so good, this seems to be plausible. But when I then use the **train_on_batch** method on net.generator or net.combined, the format of the returned loss does not match my expectations. I found out that I can check this by using **model.metrics_names**:

- **net.generator.metrics_names** -> ['loss']
- **net.combined.metrics_names** -> ['loss', 'sequential_15_loss', 'discriminator_loss']

> **My Question is**: Why does my net.combined loss contain 3 instead of just two elements as I defined (loss=[generator_loss_fct,
>   'binary_crossentropy'). I don't want it to be 3 elements long.
>   Additionally the first two are almost always the same, or at least
>   very very very similar.

Does someone understand this? If yes, please explain me why this is like this and if I did something wrong. :)

Thanks in advance!

```
    # build and compile the generator
    self.encoder = self._build_encoder(input_shape, encoder_filters, kernel_size, latent_size)
    self.decoder = self._build_decoder(self.encoder.layers[-1].output_shape[1:], decoder_filters, kernel_size)
    self.generator = Sequential([self.encoder, self.decoder])

    # compile for non-adversarial training
    self.generator.compile(loss=generator_loss_fct, optimizer=self.optimizer)

    # get the inputs
    masked_img= Input(self.input_shape, name='masked-image')
    filled_img = self.generator(masked_img)

    # build and compile the (global) discriminator
    self.discriminator = self._build_discriminator(input_shape, discriminator_filters, kernel_size)
    self.discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=self.optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    # let the discriminator judge the validity of the reconstruction
    valid = self.discriminator(filled_img)

    # we freeze the discriminator when training the generator
    self.discriminator.trainable = False

    # build and compile the combined adversarial model
    self.combined = Model(masked_img, [filled_img, valid])
    self.combined.compile(loss=[generator_loss_fct, 'binary_crossentropy'], loss_weights=[self.alpha, self.beta], optimizer=self.optimizer)
```

Comment: Do you think that your question remains unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a multioutput model, Keras will report the total loss, together with the loss corresponding to each output.

Besides, if, as you say, the first two losses are so close, probably your last loss does nothing.
If you are willing to train a GAN model you can take a look at [this Keras example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_acgan.py)